# Blender Geometry Nodes - error No Named Attributes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]On 3.2.0 - Attempting to follow tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwOHqH60X-0&t=28s
In the image: Fence GEO is a cube; Object info is a curve of the chain link; Modifier shows two error messages:
Output Attributes
No Group Output attributes connected
Internal Dependendencies
No named attributes used

How do I fix this?
If I change Object Info to Original the chain shows up.
[image]

---

Thanks for the help.   I have found my geo node mesh way way off center before. Not the problem this time.

After working on it some more these messages are apparently only warnings.
[image]

I was using the curve to mesh with profile by the curve Circle - changing the radius  did nothing to the size of the output - still shows these error messages.
Reduced it down still showed the errors; simplified still showed the errors.

I went back to start modeling again and found the chain CRV under Object Data Properties -> Geometry -> Extrude =1 cm;  set extrude to zero; then the Geo Node Curve Circle radius worked.
Apparently the manual modeled Curve Extrude overrides whatever Geo Nodes attempts to add as a Profile.

Comment: I would unzoom your viewport, I'm sure your mesh is somewhere in the distance since "relative" moves the mesh relatively to the source object

Comment: The "error messages" you describe here ("No group output attributes connected" and "No named attributes used") have nothing at all to do with the problem you are talking about here (and below in your answer)... Therefore, I think that the question should be closed. ...or share your file with us to better understand the "problem". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These are not error messages, but information that can help you to see from the outside if any inputs/outputs are used in the *Geometry Nodes*.

Since you have not created or are not using any additional *Group Inputs*, the message *"No group output attributes connected"* is displayed.

Since you have not created/used any group outputs, the message *"No named attributes used"* is displayed.

So everything is exactly as it should be.